# Отличие type=hidden от display:none

Tags: jquery

Приветствую. Хотелось бы узнать отличие и как изменить сию запись `var serializeValues = $(this).find("input[type='hidden'], :input:not(:hidden)").not('.table-element').serialize();` чтобы выбирала `type=hidden` но не `display:none`? Она почему то не работает, не выбирает ни то ни другое

Comment: input type=hidden - используется только для формы, что бы передавать скрытую информацию о сайте (например шифрованый ай-ди  сессии). Видимым он не бывает (в этом вся суть). А display:none используется в стилях, что бы спрятать временно или постоянно елемент который может быть видимым.

Comment: ну это в принципе понятно, что насчет второго вопроса?

Comment: заменить `:input:not(:hidden)"` на `:input:visible"` ?

Comment: хм, помогло, но насколько я понимаю, эти выражения эквивалентны ведь...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Ваш `input type=hidden` - скрытое поле. Оно никак не отображается на веб-странице (скрыто), но присутствует на ней. Используется, как правило, для передачи информации, например, в формах. А `display: none` - временно удаляет (а не визуально скрывает) элемент из документа. Занимаемое им место не резервируется и веб-страница формируется так, словно элемента и не было.

Источники: [display](https://webref.ru/css/display) | [input type](https://webref.ru/html/input/type)

2) Необходимо заменить `:input:not(:hidden)` на `:input:visible`, т.к. [:hidden](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B) в вашем коде это фильтр jQuery, который помогает уточнить выборку по другим селекторам. Он похож на псевдокласс CSS, отсюда и путаница, вероятно.

Больше информации по ссылкам:

[jQuery - Селекторы](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B) | 
[jQuery - Видимые элементы](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B) | [jQuery - Невидимые элементы](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B)